# How to debug google app script function run from Node js

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have followed this official documentation from Google: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute to call an Apps Script function from my Node.js server and it's working fine.

The problem I have is that at some point in time, I get the following exception:

```
errors:[{message:'Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).',domain:'global',reason:'rateLimitExceeded'}]}
```

I have checked my Google Cloud quota for the Script API and looks like I have not exceeded any of my quotas, I have also checked my Apps Script failed execution but I can't find anything there... [image: Google Cloud Apps script API quota]

[image: app script dashboard]

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: app script is a mistery when it comes to error messages, could it be you are hitting one of its hard limits ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

Comment: @Pievis okay thank you, I thought there are some tips to trace the error

Comment: In my knowledge I think you have everything covered, by looking at the api page in gcp

Comment: I can see the error rates but I cannot find the exact causes(Script runtime or Simultaneous executions, Custom function runtime, etc...)